# How to execute ts function inside js file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the typescript file `file1.ts`

```
export function Hello(str: string) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

I have file `index.js`

```
{
   require('./some.js'); 
}
```

and script in package.json

```
"run": "node index.js"
```

How can I run the function from `ts` file in `index.js`

Comment: Please follow this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/9739044

Which framework you are working in?

Comment: you need transpile the typescript file to a javascript file first, unless you're using `ts-node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import a `ts` or `es` file inside a `js` file to execute it using node, you need to be able to transpile the imported files to javascript on fly. You can use `babel-register` plugin to achieve this.

You will have to include babel-register in the index.js like this

```
require('babel-register')({
    plugins: [/* List of plugins */],
    cache: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'
});
```

If you use babel.rc, you dont need to include the plugins here. You can use `@babel/preset-typescript` plugin to transpile `ts` to `js`.

**Edit:**

You can import any exported values from a ts file, just like you would import from any other file.

```
var Hello = require('file1.js')
```

Comment: your answer also gives me another idea, that ok for me now: add ts-node to packages `yarn add ts-node`, update `packages.json` with `"run": "ts-node index.js"`,  import function in this way `const hello = require('./tsgen/codeGenerator').Hello; hello('test');`. It is working - minimum work.
`

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports let the script load other scripts as needed:

```
<script type="module">
  import('hello.mjs').then(module => {
  module.hello('world');
});
</script>
```

Refer to this

[Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/9739044)

Comment: I don't think that's the question - the OP is asking how to run a TypeScript file within a JavaScript file; that's more than just `import` because the TS needs to be compiled first